# react/firebase, retrive all the user posts in the firebase and show them on the screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm new at react, I try to write a social website. Now I need to display the post posted by the user on the screen. The user is a collection in my firebase database, and posts is one of the fields, but no matter how I modify the code, the interface display is blank. My firebase is already set up under the lib path. Any tips would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {firebase, FieldValue} from '../lib/firebase';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const App = () => {
  const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     const db = firebase.firestore();
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('users').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const postsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().posts).flat();
      setUserPosts(postsData);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {userPosts.map((post, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          <p>{post.content}</p>
          {/* Add any other fields you want to display here */}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in developer console? If so please add then to your question